# Module Prestashop grafting hook module is differents server dev and préproduction

Tags: php, module, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I developed a module for product suggestion. I developed it on the prestashop of our server. After that I wanted to put it in pre-production but in "position, graft a module" on the pre-production my hook does not appear while on the version of it works well. The version of prestashop is the same and I just import them module correctly.

[image]

[image]

the installation was done the same. the version is 1.7.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, since it is a custom hook, I guess it was not registered correctly in the pre-production database.

Make sure your module installer registers the hook correctly, also check that it appears in the "Design" section and check you DB, make sure that the **id_hook** is registered properly and connected to your id_module (check the **ps_hook** and **ps_hook_module** tables).

Comment: My Hook is well registered in a ps_hook and ps_hook_module